# javascript select Object in modal window. IE8

Tags: javascript, window, modal-dialog

I have a weird problem with SELECT object in Modal Window.

in my HTML code I have a button by clicking on which I open a modal window in which I load a JSP page. In this JSP page I have a drop-down list defined using  tag and I have a button which calls a Javascript function which suppose to show me the items selected and eventually return them to the parent window. The problem is when I am trying to read a length or selectedIndex it fails ( I don't see alert statement ). Due to the security regulations in my Company I am unable to see the Error message or the source code.

Here is the code :

Javascript which opens modal window :

```
 var oReturnValue = window.showModalDialog('addnewfilters', '', "dialogHeight:505px;dialogWidth:300px;resizable:yes;center:1;");
```

HTML and Javascript in the Modal Window :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
        <title> Add New Field as a Filter</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/filters.js">

        var oReturnObject = new Object();

        window.onbeforeunload = function()
        {           
              window.returnValue = oReturnObject; 
        }

        </script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
         * Adds a one or more Filters
         */
        function addNewField(selectObj){

            var sFields = "";
            var fieldsArray = new Array();

            alert("List name : " + selectObj.name);
            alter("List length : " + selectObj.length);

            for(i=0; i < selectObj.length; i ++){
               alert("Element : " + selectObj[i]);

               if (selectObj[i].selected){
                sFields = selectObj[i] + ",";
                fieldsArray.push(selectObj[i]);
               }  
            }                         
            oReturnObject.selFields = sFields;
            window.close();            
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>                  
                <select id="filtersList" name="filtersList" multiple="multiple">
                     <option value="dtcreated">DTCREATED</option>
                     <option value="dtupdated">DTUPDATED</option>
                     <option value="vchstatus">VCHSTATUS</option>
                     <option value="intjrnlcnt">INTLJRNCTL</option>
                </select>

                <button id="btnAddFilter" onClick="addNewField(document.getElementById('filtersList'))">Add Fields to Filter</button>
                <button id="btnCancel" onclick="window.close();">Cancel</button>                              

    </body>
</html>
```

When I click on "Add Fields to Filter" button I get an alert that shows me the SELECT tag name and the next is not popping up.

Is it something with IE8 and modal Windows? I tried the same thing in regular window and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should *always* check your error console:

This is a syntax error.

```
alter("List length : " + selectObj.length);
```

Comment: I also tried ** selectObj.options.length ** and still didn't work. However it worked perfectly fine when I use this statement in the window.onload function in the same modal window.